# Show count of past due items on Looker Studio Scorecard

Tags: looker-studio

I feel that this should be easy. On my Looker Studio Dashboard, I want to display a scorecard that shows the sum of past due items. The source data is a Google Spreadsheet.

Another set of conditions:

```
Include Status = In Progress
Include Status = Pending for Clarification
Include Status = Manager’s Review
Exclude Status = Completed (so they are out of the equation)
```

This scorecard's metric is a calculated field with IF statement:

```
IF(Days to Due<=-1,1,0)
```

In addition, a filter is applied with the abovementioned conditions:

```
Include Status = In Progress
Include Status = Pending for Clarification
Include Status = Manager’s Review
Exclude Status = Completed (so they are out of the equation)
```

This approach does not work because the scorecard shows "No Data" when it should show "1"
(a test item's Days to Due is currently -1, therefore it should be counted by the IF formula along with the filter conditions)